# jqGrid; date being fetched in the json format is not being displayed in the table. Not able to format the date either

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

This is my first time working with a jqGrid. The date is not being displayed at all in the table. The data is encoded in json format. On debugging I found the date being fetched is in unicode(not sure) format which is basically a 13 digit number. 
I have tried using srcformat as 'U' or 'u'. But neither works. I have tried creating a custom formatter but that is returning an undefined date.

The JSON value is '1380556800000' for example. Also, I would like to mention that the java object is of type Timestamp.

It would be great if you could point out what exactly I'm doing wrong here.
Thanks in advance

```
function searchSchePtn(){
    var sParam = {
    outPtnId : $('#outPtnId').val(),
    floutScheCd : $('#scheCd').val(),
    floutScheNm : $('#scheNm').val(),
    schePtn : $('#schePtn').val(),
    status : $('#status').val(),
};

var schePtnList = null;

SchePtnAccessor.getFloutSchePtnList(sParam, {
    callback : function(value) {
        schePtnList = JSON.parse(value);
    },
    async : false
});

$('#schePtnList').jqGrid('GridUnload');
$('#schePtnList').jqGrid(
        {
            data : schePtnList,
            datatype : 'local',
            height : 250,
            rowNum : 10,
            rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
            colNames : [ 'Schedule Id', lang.getMessage('出力パターン名称', 'Output Pattern Name'), 'Schedule Code', 'Schedule Name', 'Schedule Pattern', 'Start Date', 'Execution Time', 'Status'],
            colModel : [ {
                name : 'floutScheId',
                index : 'floutScheId',
                hidden : true,
        },{
                name : 'outPtnName',
                index : 'outPtnName',
                width : 150,
                sorttype : "String"
            }, {
                name : 'floutScheCd',
                index : 'floutScheCd',
                width : 150,
                sorttype : "String"
            }, {
                name : 'floutScheNm',
                index : 'floutScheNm',
                width : 150,
                sorttype : "String"
            }, {
                name : 'schePtn',
                index : 'schePtn',
                width : 50,
                sorttype : "String"
            }, {
                name : 'sDate',
                index : 'sDate',
                width : 100,
                formatter: 'date',
                formatoptions: {srcformat:'U', newformat:'d-M-y H:i'}
            } , {
                name : 'actTime',
                index : 'actTime',
                width : 50,
                sorttype : "String"
            }, {
                name : 'status',
                index : 'status',
                width : 50,
                sorttype : "String"
            }],
            pager : '#schePtnListPager',
            viewrecords : true,
            gridview : true,
        });
```

};

Answer (score 1):

i think this question is answered before..not sure if you have same issue but try look at this....
[jqgrid date formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747782/jqgrid-date-formatting)

> **Updated**

```
name: 'myDate',
        index: 'myDate',
       align: 'left',
          sortable: true,
          formatter: 'date',
         formatoptions: 
        {srcformat: 'u', newformat: 'd/m/Y H:i:s'},
          width: 70,
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/4467/)

Comment: No it's not the same as the question you mentioned since the date/time there is in ISO Long format whereas in my case it's in the Epoch format(or the Unix timestamp format).

Comment: what version of jqgrid are you using ?